# Accessing room calendar in EWS returns "No mailbox with such guid"

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I am trying to get the list of meetings from a room shared calendar using Microsoft Exchange (EWS) API and it's returning this error: **No mailbox with such guid**

```
var service = new ExchangeService();
service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
service.Url = new Uri("exchangeUrl");

var startDate = DateTime.Today;
var endDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
var cv = new CalendarView(startDate, endDate);
var mailboxToAccess = "room_email_address@mycompany.com";
var calendarFolderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, mailboxToAccess);
var appointments = service.FindAppointments(calendarFolderId, cv); // << Exception happens here
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the user that you're using in

```
service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
```

is a licensed user, with their own mailbox, that has been granted access to the Shared Mailbox in question.

Comment: I can access everything through Outlook, therefore it means the account I am using does have permissions to request data

Comment: Outlook uses MAPI so its not the same I would suggest you give it a try with the ewseditor https://ewseditor.codeplex.com/ as well

Answer (score 1):

**Use this, if you're trying to access Outlook mail box from an application end.

Language:C#**

```
service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");   
service.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
```

Comment: The info with the hard-coded service URL for the O365 EWS was it in my case. Previously I had used the autodiscover URL for the user which I used to authenticate - and with that, it always throwed the error: No mailbox with such guid.